# What is the difference of A[i] and A[i,:] in n-dimensional(n>1) numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Suppose X be a n-dimensional (n>1) numpy array.

Is there any difference between X[i] and X[i,:]?

for instance,

```
X = np.zeros((3,3))

print(X[i])
 #[ 0.  0.  0.]
print(X[i,:])
 #[ 0.  0.  0.]
```

I think it is totally same but in my guess, I think there is some difference in

terms of speed to access.

But I don't know exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

> If the number of objects in the selection tuple is less than N , then : is assumed for any subsequent dimensions.
>
> An integer, i, returns the same values as i:i+1 except the dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by 1. In particular, a selection tuple with the p-th element an integer (and all other entries :) returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension N - 1.

They are the same.  As shown in another answer there is a difference in timings, but the times are in `ns`, where Python parsing times, and layers of function calls can make a difference.  But I'd welcome any correction based on an actual reading of the numpy code.

```
In [190]: X = np.zeros((3,3))
In [191]: X.__array_interface__
Out[191]: 
{'data': (45249072, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (3, 3),
 'version': 3}
```

The slice properties are the same:

```
In [192]: X[0].__array_interface__
Out[192]: 
{'data': (45249072, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
In [193]: X[0,:].__array_interface__
Out[193]: 
{'data': (45249072, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
```

the timings:

```
In [194]: timeit X[0]
172 ns ± 2.43 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [195]: timeit X[0,...]
175 ns ± 0.105 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [196]: timeit X[0,:]
264 ns ± 15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

compare the time to return a copy (as opposed to a view):

```
In [199]: timeit X[[0]]
6.73 µs ± 48.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and the same indexing for a column:

```
In [206]: timeit X[:,1]
262 ns ± 5.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [207]: timeit X[...,1]
177 ns ± 2.15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

(and I get the same times for a much larger array - supporting the idea that any time differences occur during parsing/setup, not during actual construction of the view.)

Answer (score 0):

X[i] is to get the ith list of X

X[i,:] is to slice the data from the ith list of X

You got the same result, but they are different actually.

Comment: I don't think so.  Both are a view of the array.  `X[i]` the `:` for the 2nd dimension is implied.  The indexing operation is the same.

Comment: interesting. I don't know this. Thanks for the correction